# Applovin Integration Error

Tags: ios

I got this error when integrating Applovin SDK:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALSdk",
>   referenced from:       objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALInterstitialAd", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***project->TARGETS->Build Settings->Achitectures*** and remove armv7 from valid architectures by double clicking the options there and then selecting armv7 and pressing '-' as shown in the image below. This might solve the problem. If it does not you may have to build the respective api which you want to add to you project and then add the respective .a file to the project.
[image]

Comment: After doing this i am getting this error 
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=armv7s armv6).

Comment: You re add armv7 and do the second step I have mentioned

Comment: For the second step you have to do something for your api that they have done here for zbarSDK(another api) [Solution for ZBar sdk problem similar to yours](http://www.federicocappelli.net/2012/10/05/zbar-library-for-iphone-5-armv7s/)